# Does XML declaration need to be in a specific encoding?

Tags: java, xml, encoding, utf-8, utf-16

I'm toubleshooting a weihstephen server implementation and am having parsing issues with a commercial test client. I am wondering if my xml document declaration needs to be in a specific encoding.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>`

the odd thing is the previous developer is writing the xml to the tcp socket interleaving a zero with each character which I'm assuming he's aiming at a unicode/UTF-16 encoding but in the generating code it is set to UTF-8.

```
Transformer serializer = tf.newTransformer();
serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```

...

```
packetData[2 * i + 0] = data[i];
packetData[2 * i + 1] = 0;
```

then the byte array packet data is sent:

```
dataOutputStream.write(packetData);
dataOutputStream.flush();
```

so in wireshark the output file looks like this:

`.<.?.x.m.l. .v.e.r.s.i.o.n.=.".1...0.". .e.n.c.o.d.i.n.g.=.".U.T.F.-.8.". .s.t.a.n.d.a.l.o.n.e.=.".n.o.".?.>`

and I'm wondering if the above is valid and whether the declaration needs to be in a specific encoding say UTF-8 and the rest of the xml document would be the encoding specified by the xml declaration or the xml declaration is simply in the encoding specified by the declaration.

Comment: UTF-16 is not just adding a zero with each character. I think it is just a bug introduced by that developer only.

Comment: I suspect the developer intentionally want to keep entire data contents in 16 bytes.  There is probably 16 bit data in the xml and wanted to keeps entire data contents in one format.  It is possible the developer was going to encrypt and alignment was important, or just make it harder for somebody to hack the decryption and adding spaces would make it a little hard to hack.  The hacker would be looking for the string ?xml and would not find it.

Comment: Regardless of the document encoding, all characters in XML processing are from the Unicode character set. All but a few Unicode characters are allowed so any processor that can't handle it should make its non-compliant limitations well known. As for the document encoding declaration and the actual encoding of the file or stream, XML libraries handle both together. The code you inherited was just written by someone who hadn't yet learned enough to do the job correctly. I would think it could be replaced by a common library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XML parser uses a variety of techniques to discover the encoding of the file. It may look for a byte order mark at the start, it may look for recognizable patterns in the initial bytes (e.g., what does `"<?xml"` look like in EBCDIC?) and it may assume that the initial bytes are in ASCII in which case it can read the encoding attribute in the XML declaration. Some of these things are prescribed by the spec, others are left implementation-defined.

If two of these techniques give different answers, e.g. if the file is actually in UTF-16 but the XML declaration says it's in UTF-8, that doesn't technically make the XML ill-formed, but it does mean the parser may not be able to make head or tail of it.

Trying to manually generate UTF-16 by inserting zero bytes looks like a really bad idea.